# Migrating from Python 2.7 to 3.8: "TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'"

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2to3

In one of the files I am seeing issue:

```
"TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'"
```

Code snippet:

```
def run_process(self, cmd):
        sh = self.is_win()
        child = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, shell=sh)
        output = child.communicate()[0].strip().split('\n')
        return output, child.returncode
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you called `subprocess.Popen()` without `text=True`, `Popen.communicate()` returns bytes as documented, and you can't split bytes with a string. You can reproduce your error with the follow snippet:

```py
>>> b'multi\nline'.split('\n')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

One fix is to use `split(b"\n")`. But since you're splitting on end of lines, I guess your command returns text, so the better solution is to pass `text=True` to `subprocess.Popen()`. The output of `cmd` will be decoded straight away, which will help see any encoding errors where you're best equipped to handle them.

Also, consider using `subprocess.run()` when the port to Python 3 is over as it's easier to use than `subprocess.Popen`.

Comment: Getting 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'subprocess' on changing Popen to run or on adding text=True.

Comment: Alternate 1:def run_process(self, cmd):
        sh = self.is_win()
        child = subprocess.run(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, shell=sh)
        output = child.communicate()[0].strip().split('\n')
        return output, child.returncode

Comment: Alternate2:
def run_process(self, cmd):
        sh = self.is_win()
        child = subprocess.Popen(cmd, text=True,stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, shell=sh)
        output = child.communicate()[0].strip().split('\n')
        return output, child.returncode